# Trie end-of-word node

Tags: data-structures, strings

I read about **TRIE** data-structure and is slightly confused about detecting end-of-word. Why do we create another node to detect *end-of-word*? why cant same node be used it. For example, we have to construct a TRIE for word CAT. Now, as per specification, there will be 4 nodes; in which last node will contain a field

> "isEndOfWord"

which will return true in this case. I am unable to understand why we couldn't use the third node "T" and return true from there.

Comment: How would you distinguish CA from CAT? What if your list of words contained both? What if it didn't?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus if my list of words will contain both then, node containing A and T; both will return true. The reason is search input is given by user and that decides whether to include CA or CAT. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Tries as defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) don't have dummy nodes, but they still have an end-of-word mechanism (implemented differently).